# Call jar file from PHP

Tags: java, php, jar

I am trying to call a jar file from PHP. If I call a simple HelloWorld jar it works well.
I'm on a Windows OS and from PHP I'm using

```
exec("java -jar e:\\path_to_jar\\Hello.jar 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output); //shows the system.out from HelloWorld class
```

But when I switch to the jar I actually need to work with, I get

> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) [8] => Could not find the main class: e:\path_to_jar\abc.jar. Program will exit. [9] => Exception in thread "main".

Both jar files have a MANIFEST file where I specified a value for Main-Class

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is the main class declared `public`?

Comment: Have you tried to run the .jar manually?

Comment: Yes the main class is public.Yes, I can run the jar file manually with success

Comment: try to add the main class in the command, after the jar path, add it with full package name, ex `com.app.abc.mainclass`

Comment: You're trying this on your localhost?

Comment: Yes I'm trying on localhost.I also included the full package name in the command, but still no luck

Comment: i am thinking about something, can you confirm that the output of `java -version` is identical, when executed from PHP and when executed manually?

Comment: exec("java -version", $output); //doesn't return anything

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you've exported your Jar file as a runnable jar file, with the library handling set to: Package required libraries into generated Jar? This is how I do it anyway's.

Comment: @kien append this `2>&1` to the end of the command don't forget, space before `2`

Comment: @Adz I created the jar with maven.I exported it as you suggested from Eclipse and now I don't have the error.Thanks!